# Intermittently getting "Message disconnected: not connected to DevTools" using Selenium with chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, macos-sonoma

I successfully ran Python Selenium scripts on my previous Mac, running Catalina. I never hit this error in that environment.

Recently, I migrated to Sonoma on a new MacBook Pro with the M3 Pro chip. The same scripts intermittently fail with *"Message: disconnected: not connected to DevTools"*.

- **MacOS**: Sonoma 14.1
- **Google Chrome**: Version 120.0.6099.199 (Official Build) (arm64)
- **Python**: 3.11.2
- **Selenium**: 4.15.2 (after upgrade)

I have searched extensively on the Internet for clues to solving this problem, tried various things, nothing works.

Note the problem is intermittent, and does not always occur at the same point in my script.

Issue not due to mismatched Chrome and chromedriver versions, as I have triple-checked these and now rely on Selenium manager to take care of this.

Removed and re-installed Chrome: no impact.

Upgraded Selenium to 4.15.2: no impact.

Tried quitting Chrome and checking Activity Monitor to ensure no chromedriver processes running and then running Python script: sometimes makes problem less intermittent.

My code to invoke the driver:

```
    #             options.add_argument("page_load_strategy = 'none'")
                    options.add_argument("start-maximized");
                    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9230")
                    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
                    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
                    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    #            return webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service = s)
                    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Enabling *page-load-strategy* had no impact. Same with *remote-debugging-port*, *no-sandbox*, and *disable-dev-shm-usage*. Likewise, disabling all options had no impact.

Sometimes, I also get the following error: *Message: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer*

Looking for clues, insights, solutions, new things to try.